# Use Root of pure function for fitting

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

i need to solve an equation for one variable in dependence of 3 parameters

```
gg[x_, \[Omega]x_, \[Omega]z_] := Solve[force[x, z, \[Omega]x, \[Omega]z] == 0, z][[6, 1, 2]].
```

What i get, is the following

```
gg[x_, \[Omega]x_, \[Omega]z_] = Root[-4.4427710843373496874144566600000*10^26 x^2 \[Omega]x^2 + 
2.28560758239644800000000000000000*10^30 \[Omega]z^2 #1 + 
1.11069277108433733641205617536723*10^27 \[Omega]z^2 #1^2 + 
2.1589680420040268140562047245972*10^23 \[Omega]z^2 #1^3 + 
2.0983043771159875881741103609327*10^19 \[Omega]z^2 #1^4 + 
1.01967263372208373631680481830640*10^15 \[Omega]z^2 #1^5 + 
1.9820428176217022632960618784981*10^10 \[Omega]z^2 #1^6 &, 6]
```

So far so good. I'm able to plot this, but it's not simply possible to fit this to data with respect to one variable with the two others as fit parameters with NonlinearModelfit

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, gg[x, \[Omega]x, \[Omega]z], {{\[Omega]x, 300000}, {\[Omega]z,40000}}, x].
```

I get following error:

```
NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: The function value {-9134.52+872.949 I,-8039.76+1794.15 I,-7765.74+2048.02 I,-7572.89+2235.07 I,-7380.16+2427.79 I} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {5} at {\[Omega]x,\[Omega]z} = {300000.,40000.}.

NonlinearModelFit[{{6.8, 0}, {36, 4.8}, {48.3, 9.5}, {58.5, 15}, {70, 
20.4}}, Root[-4.4427710843373496874144566600000*10^26 x^2 \
\[Omega]x^2 + 
2.28560758239644800000000000000000*10^30 \[Omega]z^2 #1 + 
1.11069277108433733641205617536723*10^27 \[Omega]z^2 #1^2 + 
2.1589680420040268140562047245972*10^23 \[Omega]z^2 #1^3 + 
2.0983043771159875881741103609327*10^19 \[Omega]z^2 #1^4 + 
1.01967263372208373631680481830640*10^15 \[Omega]z^2 #1^5 + 
1.9820428176217022632960618784981*10^10 \[Omega]z^2 #1^6 &, 
6], {{\[Omega]x, 300000}, {\[Omega]z, 40000}}, x]
```

Do I need to convert the gg[x,omegax,omegaz] function somehow to a normal function to apply NonlinearModelFit?

Edit:
My force function is:

```
pot[x_, z_, fx_, fz_] := 
 m/2*((2*\[Pi]*fx)^2*x^2*r0^4)/(r0 + z*Tan[\[Theta]])^4 + 
  m/2*(2*\[Pi]*fz)^2*z^2
 force[x_, z_, fx_, fz_] := D[pot[x, z, fx, fz], z]
```

Here some sample data:

```
data = {{6.8, 0}, {36, 4.8}, {48.3, 9.5}, {58.5, 15}, {70, 20.4}};
```

Comment: As the error message states, gg has a complex value at some values of your parameters. NonlinearModelFit needs to fit Real valued functions. Can you edit your post to include your exact Force function and include a small sample of your data, just enough that there should be some fit, even if it is not the best fit you are looking for in the end, and which still gives exactly the same error? Then someone else can actually run your code, see where the error is coming from and then try to offer advice on how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: can you explain why you are always picking the 6th solution returned by solve? Some other choice might be real.

Comment: some trail and error showed me that the 6th root is the one i'm actually looking for. Every other root is ether complex or a big negative number(which i'm not interested in). One problem could be that there's only one root, when x=0 which leads to an error, when taking 6th element of the solution of solve. i tried piecewise definition to get rid of that error, but did'nt help with the fit.